# MIPS assembly not running on different machine

Tags: mips

I'm doing a group project with MIPS assembly, and when I uploaded my copy of the code with my groups they're unable to run it. I've also tried it on my laptop and its still not working, just when its on my desktop I can run it.

When I run it on the laptop it gives me a runtime exception and address out of range. The desktop runs just fine.

Any idea what's causing this? Thank you

Comment: What code?  What are you using to run it?

Comment: It's a code that plays a word game, that loads from a .txt file. I'm using MARS 4.5 to run it. The code is pretty long and i'm not sure if I can post it.

Comment: So, I did a little bit of debugging, and found out its the .txt file thats maybe causing an error. Right now it looks like this: wordbank: .asciiz "word.txt"
Am I doing something wrong with the pathing on my laptop?